# What is the impact of Importing modules using barrels vs specific files on the bundle size?

Tags: typescript, angular

According to angular 2 style guide, it is a good practice to define a file for each directory that will contain all the imports of the nested files.

I completely agree with that and have already started using this approach.

Now, my questions is:

Is there any impact on the final bundle size depending on each approach I use?

For instance this(Considering that /core has dozens of exportable classes:

```
import {DataClient} from './../core'
```

vs this:

```
import {DataClient} from './../core/interfaces/data.service'
```

Additionally, what happens for third party libs, like rxjs? Whats the difference between the following snippets?

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

I mentioned rxjs because even in angular documentation is advised to import each operator separately.

Answer (score 3):

This will load all exported modules + dependencies from `core`:

```
import {DataClient} from './../core'
```

This will load module `data.service` (ts file with export/import statement is a module) + dependencies of this module:

```
import {DataClient} from './../core/interfaces/data.service'
```

This will load full 'rxjs' library (all operators):

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs'
```

This will load only `Observable` implementation from `rxjs`:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
```

Comment: So when loading `DataClient` from `./../core`, is it right to imply that it's most optimal to load the single file, as this avoids loading and potentially activating an entire set of modules?